# PHP html as string

Tags: php, html, string

I wonder if something like the following is possible?

```
<?php $html_string =  ?>
    <div>
        some html
    </div>
<?php ; 
 echo $html_string;
?>
```

That is, can PHP "receive" the following HTML and assign it to a variable?

Comment: are you asking if it's possible or why it's possible?

Comment: I wonder why, if possible, you would want to. Just make a string and print it.

Comment: i'm asking how it's possible, the code above is wrong.

Comment: ^ how can it be possible if it's wrong?

Comment: No you cannot do this in php, see the other answers for alternative

Comment: other answers are compeleteley wrong, except for EOF

Comment: @Benedictus they are not wrong they are alternative, maybe they arent suited for your purpose

Comment: Your way is pretty not readable for a code reader. Imagine you are used to think that when the php tag is closed, the HTML starts and is about to be printed. And what? Someone just assigns it to variable, but not printing it. However, as some of the answers stated, your way is Heredoc syntax, but you will need to be in PHP opened

Comment: @RoyalBg thanks for a comment, i wonder if there's a way to do smth like that with output buffer ob_start()

Comment: Yes, the output buffer, will prevent the direct output sending

Comment: I updated my answer to address output buffering.

Comment: Thanks to guys who understood my questionably formatted question, i've learned a few things today. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you described is invalid, because PHP automatically adds a `;` before `?>` in this case, making the code be: `$html_string = ;`.

One alternative would be to use output buffering:

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
    <div>
        some html
    </div>
<?php
 $html_string = ob_get_clean();
 echo $html_string;
?>
```

Another would be to use an anonymous function, in which case the `;` is not inserted:

```
<?php $html_string = function() { ?>
    <div>
        some html
    </div>
<?php
 };
 $html_string();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc)

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOF
    <p>My</p>
    <p>HTML</p>
    <p>HTML</p>
EOF;

echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an "easy" multi-line string assignment method, there's [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOL
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah 
EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$html_string = '<div>somehtml</div>';
echo $html_string;
```

Or you could store the HTML in its own file and load it with [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$html_string = file_get_contents("myhtml.html");
```

Or with output buffering:

```
ob_start();
include "myhtml.html";
$html_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: no, in fashion i've posted.

Comment: @Benedictus You can't store text in a variable like that.

Comment: mok, that's the part of what I'm asking

Comment: @Benedictus At this point I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the other answers if you want to store your html as is, you can use https://www.php.net/file_get_contents to load a .html file into a string and then echo it. a start for making templates haha